# Using SSR hydration

Tags: svelte

I was trying to create an interactive article with Svelte that included a pre-rendered version of the html using the ssr options. Unfortunately my hydration code blows away all the pre-rendered DOM nodes when it loads. I would love to have a static index.html page that loads and get hydrated with a svelte bundle, but doesn't blow away the entire page because most it will be static `<p>` tags with text. Is this possible and am I doing something stupid here?

https://github.com/shancarter/svelte-ssr

Answer (score 0):

I tested your components with `svelte v1.51.0`, `rollup v0.52.3` and `rollup-plugin-svelte v4.0.0`, and client hydration [seems to work as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3u1QH.gif).